# Jersey LoggingFeature : in web.xml

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get Jersey LoggingFeature to work. 
But all the examples i can find use the ResourceConfig to register it explicitly.

I don't have a ResourceConfig or Application subclass, how can i enable the LoggingFeature from web.xml ?

EDIT :

I have tried :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    ...
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet>
```

as well as :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        ...
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to log the requests without having an `Application` subclass.

One way is to declare the `LoggingFilter` in your `web.xml` file.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value
</init-param>
```

Notice that this logger is deprecated by Jersey, and it will be removed in future version.

The other way is to define your own `ContainerRequestFilter`/`ContainerResponseFilter` to do logging. Make sure  this class is in a package which will scanned by Jersey for resource and providers classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // replace by your own logging code
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", requestContext.getMethod(), requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: declaring it in web.xml doesn't work for me. It works though if i subclass ResourceConfig and register the LoggingFeature/Filter there.

Comment: `<init-param>` is a param to your servlet container declaration, I guess you  probably just pasted the `<init-param>` to somewhere else in your `web.xml` file ?

Comment: no, i put it inside <servlet> tag, while declaring the servlet in web.xml. Anyways if I put it somewhere else it gives me error on the IDE.